# Conditional Refresh Page:javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh

Ok coming straight to the point

I have a text box and few other things on a page
if the user is typing in the textbox the page should not refresh otherwise it should refresh after a certain interval

I searched alot and cannot find anything similar

I am new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of this. A check runs every 3 seconds. if nothing has been typed in it will refresh, if something has been typed in it will wait 3 seconds before refreshing.

http://jsfiddle.net/9ARrG/

HTML

```
<input onkeyup="resetTimer = true">
```

JS

```
resetTimer = false;
setInterval(function() {
    if(!resetTimer) {
        location.reload();
    }
    resetTimer = false;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: your answer works good but the problem is that after the user has stopped typing and he clicked on submit at the next 3 sec it will submit the value of textbox again..same problem withovercodes answer.Can you tell me how to resolve that?

Comment: Sure the proper way would be to clear the interval on submit. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ARrG/4/

Comment: Any luck? I think that should answer your question

Comment: Yes got the solution.Redirected to other page after submit and redirected back.Thank you all.Sorry for late answer went to sleep after that

Answer (score 0):

Give your input/textarea an id

```
<input id="textbox" />
// OR
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
```

Then, setup a timer to refresh the page. If there's a change, reset the timer.

```
var originalTimer = 15000; // here's the original time until page refreshes
var timer = originalTimer; // timer to track whether to refresh page
// now every 1 second, update the timer
setInterval(function() {
    timer -= 1000; // timer has gone down 1 sec
    // if timer is less than 0, refresh page
    if (timer <= 0) window.location.reload();
},1000); // repeat every 1 second (1000 ms)
document.getElementById("textbox").onchange = function() {
    // detect textbox changes, reset timer
    timer = originalTimer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `document.activeElement` property to conditionally determine what element has focus.

```
function refreshPageUnlessFocusedOn (el) {

  setInterval(function () {
    if(el !== document.activeElement) {
      document.location.reload();
    }
  }, 3000)

}

refreshPageUnlessFocusedOn(document.querySelector('textarea'));
```

Check out the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Avy/3/) for a working sample.